# How can I create an enterprise service with the local XML file?

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, abap

I want to create an enterprise service. I have the XML file in my hand but the system wants WSDL. How can i solve this situation?

**note:** I'll make the data source local. I have an XML file. How can I convert it to WSDL ?

Comment: Don't post two questions for the same problem. Probably there are XML-to-WSDL tools, which are not specific to SAP of course. At least these creation helpers can propose something, but may not give a WSDL valid for other XML of the same nature (ex.: how to know if a "line" is a line or a table with one line... cannot be solved, it can just be a default proposal)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Because; WSDL contains methods, message types, ports, binding, etc. Your xml is only sample data for a message type. You need to complete missing parts. If there is soap server, you can get wsdl or missing info from it.

Comment: @serkanbasdag The types described in the WSDL conform XSD, so you may also find a "XML to XSD" converter, then adjust it manually, and also complete manually the rest that mkysoft describes.